# Go lang how to check if float value is actually int

Tags: go

```
func isFloatInt(floatValue float64) bool{
//What's the implementation here?

}
```

**Test cases:** 
input: 1.5 output: false;
input: 1 output: true;
input:1.0 output: true;

Comment: Any thoughts? ..

Comment: Test if its equal to its own [`Floor`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Floor) ?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Trunc

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just [checked on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1C9GdJWK_6), this does the right thing with NaN as well.

```
func isIntegral(val float64) bool {
    return val == float64(int(val))
}
```

Comment: As a fresh hand of go lang, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13):

You could achieve it by doing a modulus

```
func isFloatInt(floatValue float64) bool {
    return math.Mod(floatValue, 1.0) == 0
}
```