# How to format int number from json's map[string]interface{} without exponent?

Tags: go

This demo: https://play.golang.org/p/7tpQNlNkHgG

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"code1":10080061,"code2":12.2}`
    data := map[string]interface{}{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &data)
    for k, v := range data {
        fmt.Printf("%v:%v, %v:%f, %v:%.0f\n", k, v, k, v, k, v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
code1:1.0080061e+07, code1:10080061.000000, code1:10080061
code2:12.2, code2:12.200000, code2:12
```

I want code1 to output `10080061` and code2 to output `12.2`.
How can I do this done.

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422587/need-to-parse-integers-in-json-as-integers-not-floats

Comment: Why are you using the %f verb if you want an int?

Comment: @Volker because `code` can be int or float.

Comment: In JSON all numbers are floats. Or just don't decode into the empty interface{}? This looks suspiciously like a XY-problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func isIntegral(val float64) bool {
    return val == float64(int(val))
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"code1":10080061,"code2":12.2, "code3": 123.23123, "code4": "string"}`

    data := map[string]interface{}{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &data)

    for k, v := range data {
        switch v.(type) {
        case float64:
           // check the v is integer or float
            if isIntegral(v.(float64)) {
                // if v is an integer, try to cast
                fmt.Printf("%v: %d\n", k, int(v.(float64)))
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", k, v)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", k, v)
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
code1: 10080061
code2: 12.2
code3: 123.23123
code4: string
```

ref

- [Go lang how to check if float value is actually int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182427/go-lang-how-to-check-if-float-value-is-actually-int?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://newfivefour.com/golang-interface-type-assertions-switch.html